How to Test an Reactive Oauth2 WebClient?
i am new to reactive Programming with Java and somehow i am missing a point in writing a test for my Reactive WebClient.
I am using The following reactive WebClientConfig
@Configuration
public class DynamicsWebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    WebClient dynamicsClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("dynamics");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth2Client)
                .build();

    }
}

Using that Client within an Controller within an "normal application run" will always work correctly doing the Oauth2 when neccecary and then reqeusting the Data, so i thought lets write a test for that so i am sure this always works. Thats why i ended up with the following TestClass
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class DynamicsClientTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebClient dynamicsClient;

    @Test
    public void testDynamicsClient() {
        String responseBody = dynamicsClient.get()
                .uri("https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/<some_ids_an_context_here>/customers")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        assertNotNull(responseBody);
        assertEquals("expectedData", responseBody);
    }

}

Running the TEST will result in the Error  serverWebExchange cannot be null at  org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.lambda$authorize$4
I thought when using @SpringBootTest the full apllication Context is loaded and i can do test as i would use the application. Yet this Error suggests that my reactive Application Test is not loaded Properly. Am i missing something is reactiveApplications handled differently?
I found out that i could use WebFluxTest but this would not load the application context properly therefor the configuration classes will not be loaded and i am still not able to do an oauth2 reactive webclient request.
I also tried:

SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK instead of WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
@EnableAutoConfiguration on my testClass
@EnableConfigurationProperties on my testClass
my application.properties contains 'spring.main.web-application-type=reactive'
i tried the solutions here Spring Boot Reactive WebClient "serverWebExchange must be null" when Spring Security OAuth is in use

Somehow my Test seams to be using "DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager" which is generating the Error. But running the Application "normaly" there seams to be used a different Manager which will not result in the same Error.
Any help with writing my supposed to be Easy Test?

just to make sure, i do wanna do an integration test,  that is when doing the request, i want the application to automatically add the oauth2 and then do the request. i then want to validate the response.

I did find the solution anticipating a similar not reactive related but oauth related Solution here `servletRequest cannot be null` -> SpringBoot - WebClient - GET request with Keycloak
To the WebClient config needs to be added an AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager as follows
@Configuration
public class DynamicsWebClientConfig {

@Bean
WebClient dynamicsClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("dynamics");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth2Client)
            .build();

}

@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {

    // Configure the authorized client provider with refresh token and client credentials
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .build();

    // Instantiate the AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, clientService);

    // Set the authorized client provider
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}
}

`
You are able to test the ReactiveEndPoint as follows:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
public class DynamicsClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient dynamicsClient;

    @Test
    public void testDynamicsClient() {
        // Use the dynamicsClient to make a request
        String responseBody = dynamicsClient.get()
                .uri(<some_api_endpint_here>/customers)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        // Validate that the response is not null and matches the expected result
        assertNotNull(responseBody);
        // You might want to validate the response further, depending on your requirements
        // For example: assertEquals("expectedData", responseBody);
    }
}

